# Functions as infinite series - graphing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, graphing-functions

Any one know how to graph a function defined as an infinite series? I need to graph the function $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(n^{2}\tan^{-1}(x- n^{2}) +n^{2}\tan^{-1}(x+ n^{2}) \bigg) $$
$x\in \mathbb R$.

**EDIT:**
So, as Peter suggested, we can simplify the function using 
 $\tan^{-1} a + \tan^{-1} b = \tan^{-1}((a + b) / (1 - ab))$
to be
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{2} \tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{2x}{ 1-(x^{2}-n^{4})}\bigg)$$

Comment: What's with the $\pm$?

Comment: OK, I fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, OK. You might want to use some arctangent difference and sum formulas that should help.

Comment: You mean something like $\tan^{-1} a + \tan^{-1} b = \tan^{-1}((a + b) / (1 - ab))$.

Comment: Indeed. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: OK, now what about some asymptotic behaviour of $\arctan$ for small values? Note that $${{2x} \over {{n^4} + 1 - {x^2}}} \sim {1 \over {{n^4}}}$$ for any nonzero $x$.

Comment: What's the radius of convergence? If the series is convergent you can plot it up to any precision using software. If it is a formal series then things are more complex.

Comment: @tst Because of my last comment, and since $\arctan x = x +o(x)$ for $x\to 0$, the radius of convergence should be infinite, as the OP is suggesting.

Comment: ok, then I see no problem. Choose $k$ and plot $$f_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\bigg(n^{2}\tan^{-1}(x- n^{2}) +n^{2}\tan^{-1}(x+ n^{2}) \bigg)$$
then the error is proportional to the first term that is being omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see a plot for $n=6,10,20$. It seems that when we sum up to $n$, we obtain a set of $2n$ vertical sigmoids bounded by the lines $y= \pi/2\cdot x$ and $y=-\pi/2\cdot  x$. You can open the image to see it larger.

$\hspace{0.5 cm}$[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graph of the series by maple 12. To see that there are jumps at some point (look where the vertical segments are), just notice that, the value of the series at $x=4.12$ is positive $9.2885852$ and at the point $x=4.13$ is negative $-3.2263024$.

[image]

This is the plot of $f'(x)$

[image]

Comment: So it looks that the function is not differentiable at $x=\pm 4, \pm 9, \dots$! I'm not sure if that is a sharp corner or a vertical asymptot! Could you plot the derivative of that function, I don't have maple 12? The function should be differentiable! The derivative is $$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{(x-n^{2})+1}+\frac{1}{(x+n^{2})+1}\bigg)$$

Comment: You mean $$f'(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{n^2}} \left\{ {{1 \over {1 + {{\left( {x - {n^2}} \right)}^2}}} + {1 \over {1 + {{\left( {x + {n^2}} \right)}^2}}}} \right\}$$ Note that this is not always valid.

Comment: yes, thanks!...

Comment: You have discontinuities at certain points.

Comment: OK, maybe it is my fault: starting with $f'(x)$ as above, what would be the graph of $f'$ and $f$? You already graphed $f$, but as I know the function $f'$ is continuous, but the $f$ is not differentiable! where is my mistake!!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I don't see any discontinuities on your graph? what do you mean?

Comment: I put more explanation on the answer.

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal: Something wrong in the graph of $f$ above: since $f'$ is strictly positive then the function $f$ must be strictly increasing, but from the values of $f$ at $x=4.12$ and $x=4.13$ it is not! Did I miss anything?! (I don't know why I couldn't add this as a comment, so I just used the answer box!)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to find an explicit formula for the sum of the series, you use that formula to plot the graph of the sum. If not, you choose $N$ large and plot the sum of the first $N$ terms of the series.

In your example I doubt that there is a simpler expression for the sum. $f$ is odd, so that it is enough to consider $x\ge0$. Since $|\tan^{-1}x|\le\max(|x|,\pi/2)$, we see that the series is uniformly convergent. The sum is discontinuous at the points $x=\pm\sqrt{1+n^4}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Below are the graphs of $8$, $16$ and $32$ terms of the sum, drawn with Mathematica 9.

[image]